# R find an area of a filled countour plot made from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, area

Is there a way to calculate an area of a filled countour like plot in r?

[image]

This image is just an example and not representative of my data. But I would, for example, want to calculate all areas above 1600. My data is in matrix for with speeds in each cell. The columns represent evenly spaced time intervals however my y axis or rows each represent a particular length and are not evenly spaced. The filled contour plot would be interpolating. I would like to bypass creating a color plot all together and just find the are of say speeds less than 35mph.

Comment: Can you please add a representative sample of your data (using `dput()` for example)?